# android - xml animation like siri wave

Tags: android, xml, android-animation

I need to create live background on `ImageView`  like siri wave animation:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

is the way to create this with xml(or java) animations on android??

thank you

Comment: Maybe you can go for a AnimationDrawable. Something like is in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777225/how-to-animate-one-item-of-layer-list) post. It's some sort of sprite with xml. In case you want to relate the animation with the level of the sound, you'll need something more complex

Comment: @mghhgm Did you achieved this effect? I also wanna do the same in one of my project. Also, I want to relate the animation with the level of sound (either playing or recording) just like siri.

Comment: I also need this effect. How did you come up with this effect ? any library ? example. Would be appreciated. For me I only need to create one line and wave like that.

Comment: ok, so I had to convert objective-c code to Java. I used this library as a reference - https://github.com/stefanceriu/SCSiriWaveformView

Comment: @Alex Thank you. I try to check this on my code. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Android Siri Wave library

Link:https://github.com/dnkilic/android-siri-wave

[image]

Comment: Note that it’s just a web view with a JS-based animation