# How to add a spinning loading icon in Splash Screen in Android?

Tags: java, android, animation, rotation, splash-screen

In the app I'm making in Android, I want to put a [spinning loading icon](https://www.google.com/search?q=spinning%20loading%20icon%20gif%20blue%20android&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjIqMDl99zvAhX7mUsFHa3DAicQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=spinning%20loading%20icon%20gif%20blue%20android&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1C3ZliybWDrcGgAcAB4AIAB2gGIAaUJkgEFMC42LjGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=oq1lYMjPC_uzrtoPrYeLuAI&bih=789&biw=1440#imgrc=5pnxlR4Pig-CDM) mid-bottom part of the screen.

This is my `splash_screen.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/hello_text"
        android:gravity="center"></item>
</layer-list>
```

And my splash screen looks like this:
[image: My current splash screen reference]

And I want to put a spinning loading icon in the bottom half of the splash screen like Skype app's splash screen:
[image: Skype Splash Screen]

How can I do that?
I've seen many answers but none on this problem. Please answer this.

Comment: add progress bar in the bottom on screen

Comment: not bar, I want to add a rotating icon. How to do that?

Comment: i dont know about in xml but i know how to create this drawable  programitlly

Comment: @Amitpandey: did you find any solution? I tried to add an item inside that `layer-list` with importing loading frames using `<animation-list` but didn't worked. do you have any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5777225/6576302

Answer (score 0):

Use Lottie Animation view.
https://lottiefiles.com/blog/working-with-lottie/getting-started-with-lottie-animations-in-android-app
example :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#88000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/animationView"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/your_lottie_json_file" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is for a normal xml file associated with an activity. But I want to put that in simple Splashscreen xml file. ProgressBar, LinearLayout are not recognizable there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want a loading circle in a drawable resource file instead of just adding one to your layout? You also have to reference to your drawable somewhere.
But if you really want it in your drawable file, you have to reference to a gif file which you add to your drawable folder(s), which already includes your text or add your text as a separate additional `item`.
Alternatively you can define your own animation documented [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation) and [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation) and also link to it in your drawable.

But if you don't need a special design I really would prefer to add just the Android `ProgressBar`. There is already a spinning loading animation as default when using it:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Just implement this in your layout xml and constraint it in the center (depends on your layout type).